# Disposal of WCF clients where soap faults are routinely used

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have been looking at the thorny issue of WCF client disposal recently.
One common solution I have seen is along the lines of:

```
try
{
    client.Call();
    client.Close();
    success = true;
}
finally
{
    if(!success) client.Abort();
}
```

This method however will abort where a soap:fault is returned by the service, even though the service has operated correctly.

If faults are returned routinely, will large numbers of aborts cause a problem to the running of my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aborts will not cause you any problems. What would cause problems is connections left open in a faulted state.

See also: [Reuse a client class in WCF after it is faulted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811142/reuse-a-client-class-in-wcf-after-it-is-faulted) and [service.close() vs. service.abort() - WCF example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155815/service-close-vs-service-abort-wcf-example)