# Need to communicate fast and often between two .NET processes

Tags: .net, wcf, vb6

So I have the following setup:

- a VB6 Application using a .NET dll on the one hand
- a .NET Service on the other end

The VB6 application uses a small interface dll to communicate to our new infrastructure (servies etc) and can hardly be changed in functionality. We choose to use WCF with a binding like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/HostCommunicator" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NETTcpBinding" contract="IHostCommunicationContract"/>
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NETTcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
```

to communicate.

This works fine and fast for single requests but one mode of the VB6 Application is a kind of batch mode where it sends an individual request for each file it processes. There will be about 1-4 requests per second.

This works fine until a number of requests is done. On my current machine and software version this are 50 requests. If I start the VB6 application over it does 50 requests again. After the limit the application hangs at 99% CPU usage.

We are using a duplex channel contract.

Comment: Nice and detailed background info but I don't see an actual question. You obviously have a problem but what're you willing to consider as far as solutions go?

Comment: We want to stay with WCF, if there is not a faster/easier/more stable way. We considered using plain TCP, too. However it should be doable without third party libraries because it's a pain to register all for interop with VB6 every time you have to do an update.

Comment: @Zebi: While this is unrelated to your problem, you might want to consider Named Pipes rather than TCP if your communication is intra-machine.

Comment: I'll think about this, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you remembered to close your connections? It looks like you are not closing the connections, just opening new ones for each request?

Comment: This seems to match the problem, a colleague just figured out the same after searching around for a while. We are currently starting a test on our test VM to verify it.

Comment: Wow it works ! :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I arrive at home. I still have to wait for the minimum time to accept to go by.

Comment: Glad to hear it seems to be working for you. Forgetting to close connections is a classic ;) I don't know if this is an issue when dealing with pure net.tcp connections, but, for http connections, be aware of the following issue regarding close vs. abort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155815/service-close-vs-service-abort-wcf-example